# How to update remote server's database by a .sql file using PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a utility in PHP like phpMyAdmin's import option, which should allow database updates to the remote server via a `.sql` file without creating a new database.

Since it's a client side utility, access to cpanel is not allowed.

The app has two kinds of working environments, offline & online.

If the client works offline, they need to take the backup of database and should update the database with remote server similar for online.

Then they have to update the database of remote server.

Comment: so, you want us to write it for you ?

Comment: @Dagon: Please don't mistake me..I'm newbie to all this stuff.Please give me a idea to get start off.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj, why don't use PHPMyAdmin itself? This is just for a suggestion because I don't fully understand the situation

Comment: @Abhay,Well of course as a developer i can use the PHPMyAdmin but my client won't.First of all,my application works in both online and offline.If my client use the app offline they'll take the backup by using my another script then they go to online and needs to update the database which is in the remote host.For that purpose, i need a script that'll update the remote server's database..Thanks!

Comment: @VijinPaulraj, in the original question you said that "The .sql file would be exported from localhost phpMyAdmin" - what does that mean? And in your comment above, you say that "they'll take the backup by using my another script". So which one of the above does the client use to generate the SQL and if is the latter, what method are you using to take the backup? I might have misunderstood though

Comment: @Abhay,Well.If my clients worked in offline they take a backup using a script which is already i've developed for my app.Hope you'll understand.Thanks.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj, I think I do understand but I'm not sure. So in offline mode, they backup using your script. And in online mode, they do it via phpMyAdmin. Right? Anyways, what method does your script employ for backing up?

Comment: @Abhay:I've edited my question and i hope you'll get my question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If you are running your PHP on a Linux system, you can try using the 'mysql' command itself. However please note that your PHP installation has the permission to run "system" commands, like system(), exec() etc.

So here is what I mean to say:

```
system("mysql -U{db_user_name} -h{db_host} -P{db_password} < {full_path_to_your_sql_file}");
```

Please replace,

{db_user_name} with the DB username,

{db_host} with the DB host,

{db_password} with the DB password,

{full_path_to_your_sql_file} with the path to your SQL file.

And this of course requires the SQL file to be uploaded.

**Solution 2:**

Read the SQL file line by line and while reading execute each statement using PHP's standard MySQL library. Something like:

```
$arrFile = file("full_path_to_sql_file.sql", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($arrFile as $q) {
    mysql_query($q);
}
```

However, this might not be as simple as it seems. If your SQL file has comments and other .sql specific statements, you might need to put checks to ignore them. Or better if the SQL file contains nothing but SQL statements.

Comment: You cannot assume a SQL file has one query per line.

Comment: you could split by `;` but still we might find `;` inside some strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular upload script to obtain the .sql file, make sure you sanitize appropriately the input string to obtain only the .sql file and text type,

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"tmpdb/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Once you have that, you can either preset their db settings defining the db using

```
mysql_select_db('dbname');
```

Then just open the sql file with fopen(); slap that sucker in a variable

```
$file = fopen("userdb.sql","r");
$usersql = fread($file, 5);
fclose($file);
```

then just throw it in a mysql_query();

```
$uploaddb = mysql_query($usersql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Those are the concepts I would suggest, alternatively you can use shell exec but then that just opens up other security concerns.

Comment: Why on Earth would you read only 5 bytes? Also, `mysql_query()` can only do one query at a time if I remember correctly.

Comment: you're correct could swap out the 5 with a filesize(), mysql query was to handle the full .sql file, if a single .sql file per upload it should be enough.

Comment: @krazybean:Thanks for your valuable response..Should i delete the existing database or whether it'll get replaced?.But in my script,i just want it should be get replaced by the existing database automatically.

Comment: @HoshSadiq,_yes,you remembered correctly.`mysql_query()` can process only one query at a time._

Comment: Thought so, you may wanna use Abhay's solution or just use BigDump. Otherwise you'll have to figure out where to explode on `;` in order to distinguish the different queries, which can be a pain if you have records in the sql dump.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/)?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually,I've got answer for my question myself.I've just pasted the php coding without config and other stuff.

```
    $filename ="test.sql";        
    mysql_select_db("test"); 

    //truncate the database.

    $result_t = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_t))
    {
       mysql_query("TRUNCATE " . $row['Tables_in_' . $mysql_database]);
    }
    // Temporary variable, used to store current query
    $templine = '';
    // Read in entire file
    $lines = file($filename);
    // Loop through each line
    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
        // Skip it if it's a comment
        if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
            continue;

        // Add this line to the current segment
        $templine .= $line;
        // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
        if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
        {
            // Perform the query
            mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
            // Reset temp variable to empty
            $templine = '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: are get solution?